# How to keep a message in console? (JS function)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript function which encrypts a text using the Caesar Cipher.

I also have an HTML form which sends data to PHP, the PHP uses `echo` to print it into `div` elements, and then, whe I press another `button` (not input), it calls the "Caesar Cipher" function (which receives the value of the `div`s with DOM).

The problem is that when the function does its job, it uses `console.log` to print it into the console - but when it prints, it only does for a half-a-second, after that the message disappears.

I think it has something to do with the page reloading or something, so if you could please explain me what to do to fix it, and why - I'd thank you very much!

**HTML & PHP:**

```
<form style="display: inline-block" method="get" action="index.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Caesar Cipher</legend>
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="number" name="shift">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        <button onclick="caesarCipher(1)">Encrypt</button> 
            //the value 1 means that the function will encrypt, and not decrypt
    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="text">
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET["submit"])) { //when the submit (input) button is pressed
            $text = $_GET["text"];
            echo htmlspecialchars($text);
                //set div (id="text") innerHTML (DOM) the value of the input field
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function caesarCipher(dir) {
    //the function takes a text, enters every letter into an array,
    //and then shifts it using the letters array (with their index)
    //it logs the array (array.join("")) into the console - here is the problem

    text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.trim().toLowerCase();
    shift = 3;
    var letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var charArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var letter = text.charAt(i);
        if(letter == " ")
            letter = " ";
        else {
            var index = letters.indexOf(letter);
            if(dir > 0)
                index = (index + shift) % 26;
            else {
                index -= shift;
                if(index < 0)
                    index += 26;
            }
        letter = letters[index];
        }
        charArray[i] = letter;
    }
    console.log(charArray.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome you can press `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+J` key to show sidebar as in the picture and check `Preserve Log` checkbox to preserve log messages.

[image]

Similar option exists in others browsers also.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the Preserve Log checkbox.

Also,

```
<!-- This is how you comment in HTML -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `localStorage`?

```
localStorage.setItem('encString', charArray.join(""));
// whenever you want to see it, even after a window reload
console.log( localStorage.getItem('encString') );
```